# how to position my customized carousel widget section that should be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, positioning

I have made the customized carousel in html using java script, in which the size of  the, scroll-able small pictures underneath the current display picture, changes on run time based upon the number of pictures. The anchors should be stuck to the first and last images, to do so i have float:right the right anchor and the position of the left anchor is changed upon run time based upon number of pictures in java script. **Now the issue is that I have to align this whole thing (small images) in the middle with respect to the display image on top**. Is there any way to do so without positioning through java script but by using css. Any suggestion will be very helpful. Everything should be responsive for all types of screens.

***Note: The page is RTL***

[Link to the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crxszp3f/24/)

```js
var totalLandMarks = 2;
   var landMarkCount =  0;
   var landMarkId =0;
   var currentIndex = 1;
   //var scrollindex = 1;
   var flag=0;
   /* uncomment when need to scroll automatically
   var screenWidth = $('#country-selected').width();
   if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
   /* the viewport is at max 360 pixels wide 
   screenWidth = 900;
 }*/
    //   $sortableList.on("sortchange", sortEventHandler);

 $( document ).ready(function() {
     console.log( "ready!" );

     for(var i=0;i<totalLandMarks;i++) {
      landMarkCount++;
      landMarkId++;

      $('#sortable').css({
    'width': ''+(((landMarkCount)*100)+((landMarkCount)*10))+'px', 
    'height': '35px', 
    'padding': '0em'
   });
   if($(".demo").width() > ((((landMarkCount)*100)-20)+((landMarkCount-1)*10))){
    $(".anchor-left").css({
     "right": ""+((((landMarkCount)*100)-20)+((landMarkCount-1)*10))+"px",
    })
   }
   else{
    $(".anchor-left").css({
     "right": "auto",
     "left": "0px",
     "position": "absolute",
     "top": "23px",
    })
   }
   

      if(landMarkCount%2 == 0){
       $("#sortable").append('<div class = "draggable overlay" data-id="'+landMarkId+'" ><img id="landMark'+landMarkId+'" class= "country-image " src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Australia Country"> <div class="bottom-border" id="landMarkBottom'+landMarkId+'"> </div></div>');
      }
      else
      {
       $("#sortable").append('<div class = "draggable overlay"  data-id="'+landMarkId+'"><img id="landMark'+landMarkId+'" class= "country-image " src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Australia Country">  <div class="bottom-border" id="landMarkBottom'+landMarkId+'"> </div></div>');
      }
      
      
    }
    updateImages();
 });
 
 function scrollRight(){

  var leftPos = $('.demo').scrollLeft();
   $(".demo").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 111}, 200);
 }
 function scrollLeft(){

  var leftPos = $('.demo').scrollLeft();
    $(".demo").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 111}, 200);
 }

 $(document).on("click",".anchor-right",function(){
  //$('.demo').scrollLeft(200);
  scrollRight();

  if(currentIndex > 1){
   currentIndex-=2;
  }
  
  updateImages();

 });
 $(document).on("click",".anchor-left",function(){
  //alert("Clicked Left");
  //$('.demo').scrollLeft(-5);
  scrollLeft();
  updateImages();
  
 });
 function updateImages(){

  if(currentIndex > totalLandMarks){ // when the highlighted pic needs to move from last to first
   currentIndex=1;
    $(".demo").animate({scrollLeft: $("#landMark"+currentIndex).offset().left}, 200);
 
    flag=0;
  }
  var imgSource = document.getElementById("landMark"+currentIndex).src;
  $("div").removeClass("overlay");
  $('[data-id=' + currentIndex + ']').addClass("overlay"); // its the purple color shown on the highlighted pics
  /*$("#landMark"+currentIndex).css({
   'opacity': '0.5'

  });*/
  $(".bottom-border").hide();
  
  $('#landMarkBottom'+currentIndex).show(); // showing the div at the bottom
  
  //console.log((scrollindex*(document.getElementById('landMarkBottom'+currentIndex).clientWidth)));
  //console.log(screenWidth+" maxWidth");
  /* un comment when you need to scroll
  if((scrollindex*(document.getElementById('landMarkBottom'+currentIndex).clientWidth)) > screenWidth){
   flag=1;
  }
  else{
   scrollindex++;
  }
  
  if(flag == 1){
   //$('#landMarkBottom'+currentIndex).focus();
   scrollLeft();
  }
  */
  
  console.log(imgSource);
  $(".display-image").html('<img class= "current-image" src="'+imgSource+'" alt="Australia Country">');
  // document.getElementByClassName(".display-image").innerHTML = imgSource;
  currentIndex++;

 }
 setInterval(function() {
   // method to be executed;
   //updateImages();

 }, 5000); 

 $(document).on("click",".draggable",function(){
  
  $('#landMarkBottom'+(currentIndex-1)).hide();
  currentIndex = $(this).attr('data-id');
  updateImages();
 });
```

```css
.country-content{
   width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      position: relative;
      padding: 0px 20px;
  }
  .draggable {
      width: 100px;
      height: 90px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      position: relative;
  }
  .overlay:before{
   position: absolute;
   content:" ";
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   display: block;
   z-index:10;
   background-color: rgba(140, 116, 158, 0.4);
   border-radius: 10px;
  }


  #sortable { 
   width: 10%; /* width of scorllable needs to be cahnged upon runtime */
   height: 35px; 
   padding: 3em;
   padding-right: 0px; 
  }
  .country-image {
      width: 100px;
      height: 90px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      right: 0px; 
  }

  #sortable > div { 
   float: right; 
  }
  .demo {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      min-height: 100px;
  }
  .current-image {
         width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 20px;
  }
  .display-image{
   width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
  }

  /* Styling the scrollbar */
  .demo::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;

  }

  .anchor-right {
      float: right;
      top: 26px;
      padding-right: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      font-size: 30px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
      width: 42px;
      border-radius: 33px;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 1000;
  }
  .anchor-left {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-right: 14px;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
      top: -74px;
      /* left: 0px; */
      right: 83px;
      z-index: 20;
      width: 42px;
      border-radius: 30px;
      background-color: white;
  }
  .anchor-left a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:grey;
  }
  .anchor-right a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color:grey;
  }
  .bottom-border{
   margin-top: 3px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #8C749E;
      display: none;
      border-radius: 16%;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 376px) {
   .display-image{
    width: 100%;
       height: 250px;
       padding: 10px 20px;
   }
   
   
  }
  
@media only screen and (min-width: 377px) and (max-width: 824px) {
   .display-image{
    width: 100%;
       height: 300px;
       padding: 10px 20px;
   }
   
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>44 HTML</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='country-selected' class="selected-country container-fluid" dir="rtl">

        <div class= "display-image">
          <img class= "current-image" src="./images/France.png" alt="Australia Country">
        </div>

      <div class="country-content ">
        <div class="anchor-right" >
          <a href="#" class= "my-arrow-right"><i class="fas fa-angle-right "></i></a>
        </div>
          <div class="demo " dir="rtl">
            <div id="sortable" dir="rtl">   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="anchor-left">
          <a href="#" class= "my-arrow-left"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your div with class demo margin 0 auto

```
.demo 
{
 width: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

and for anchor-right

```
right:126px;
```

for anchor-left add inline style

```
style="right: 308px;"
```

Comment: I cant fix the right: of any anchors as the pictures count is dynamic. Secondly the .demo should expand upon addition of pictures (make landmarkcount in java script to 1 or 2 or 10) and once the size of demo is equal to the size of the screen it should stop increasing and stuck there, the arrows(anchors) should also move according to the width of demo and the should be stuck as in the link send.

Comment: Then you have to use javascript and positioned the elements based on count

Comment: then i have to make a formula which is very difficult that would work responsively